# Choosing rows containing only times between time x and time y

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, time-series

I have a time series with a column df$Time. I also have a column containing the time of sunrise (df$Sunrise) and another containing the time of sunset (df$Sunset) for that day.

I would like to separate my data into two parts, day and night. I.e. I want to select rows in which the time is between sunrise and sunset for day and between sunset and sunrise for night.

I'm not sure what the best way of going about this is. Is it possible to use time in an ifelse statement? Or is there some function which would help me that I don't know about?

df$Time is stored as a factor currently. df$Sunrise and df$Sunset are stored as POSIXct.

Example of my data:

```
Time       Sunrise               Sunset
00:01:00   2009-09-17 07:41:30   2009-09-17 20:05:30
00:02:00   2009-09-17 07:41:30   2009-09-17 20:05:30
00:02:00   2009-09-17 07:41:30   2009-09-17 20:05:30
00:04:00   2009-09-17 07:41:30   2009-09-17 20:05:30
```

In this sample I would like all times shown to appear as night.

Comment: Can you show some sample data? It's important to know whether df$Time is stored as a date, number, or character value, and what the values look like.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.day<-df[df$Time>df$Sunrise & df$Time<df$Sunset, ]
df.night<-df[df$Time<df$Sunrise & df$Time>df$Sunset, ]
```

Without having some data to look at, I think this should provide some help. Essentially you are creating two data frames, one with only the rows with df$Time during the day, and one during the night

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working for the day data frame but returning 0 observations for night, returning that none of the values are between sunset and sunrise. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

This will hopefully clear things up.

```
# read in (slightly edited) data
df<-data.frame(Time=c("07:40:00","07:42:00","15:02:00","20:06:00"),Sunrise=c("2009-09-17    07:41:30","2009-09-17 07:41:30","2009-09-17 07:41:30","2009-09-17 07:41:30"),Sunset=c("2009-09-17 20:05:30", "2009-09-17 20:05:30", "2009-09-17 20:05:30", "2009-09-17 20:05:30"))

# convert character to POSIXct
df$Sunrise<-as.POSIXct(df$Sunrise,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df$Sunset<-as.POSIXct(df$Sunset,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# add date to Time variable and convert to POSIXct
df$Time<-as.POSIXct(paste(strptime(df$Sunrise,"%Y-%m-%d"),df$Time),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# identify times during the day
df.day<-df[df$Time>df$Sunrise & df$Time<df$Sunset, ]
# identify times NOT during the day
df.night<-df[!(df$Time>df$Sunrise & df$Time<df$Sunset), ]
```

I should have used the not (!) operator in my previous response for finding the night times. I had thought you had just a numeric variable for time and I haven't worked with POSIXct data before. This should solve the problems though.